# Smooth Line View Changing Color

Tags: objective-c, ios, cgcontext

I'm using the smooth line view app by levin nunnik, but the rewritten version by Ginamin.

I've a view controller with a view in it. Down I've some buttons. I'm trying to change the stroke colour by pressing a button. For example pressing the button named Red the stroke colour becomes red and so on..

The function that stroke set the strokeColor is this:

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
```

I've tried to change the `lineColor` property when pressing the button, but nothing happens. Some help? :(

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the original program, plus features such as undo / redo / clear / (changing color).
The program is not very complete, if there are interested people together to exchange ideas.
Thank

source code link : https://github.com/yusenhan/Smooth-Line-View

Comment: Nice work man, the only defect i got is there is a white glitches in lines , you see it in your screenshot also..If you can fix it it would be nice , Thank you

Comment: i can't understand?
can you post screenshot and he wrong place to draw the circle. thanks

Comment: http://imgur.com/U1hYP, please have a look at this image , i just aded arrow pointing towards the white glitches in line ,

Comment: CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound); instead of CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapButt); in SmoothLineView.m
but you will fond other bugs.
Problems occur when color alpha < 1.0.